# Using ggplot2 to create graphs in separate colors for each condition (time series data)

Tags: r, variables, colors, ggplot2

If this has been answered somewhere before, please point me in the right direction. I've honestly tried, but haven't found anything that addresses this specific issue:

I have collected time-series data from 20 individuals. Specifically, relative pupil size (y) over time (=x, 51 time bins) in response to 60 image/sound stimuli. There are two within-subject manipulations: half of the stimuli (=30) are emotional, the other 30 are neutral. Half of both emotional and neutral stimuli were cued during prior sleep.

So, in total, we have 15 emotional & reactivated, 15 emotional & non-reactivated, 15 neutral & reactivated & 15 neutral & non-reactivated (2x2 valcode vs. repcode). I have one column describing the valence (emotional vs. neutral) called "valcode" (1= neutral, 2 = emotional) and one column defining reactivation status "repcode" (0= non-reactivated, 2 = reactivated).

Here are the first lines of the data:

```
    head(df)
      time valcode  pupil_size repcode stimuli subject 
    1    0       2 0.000000000       0     1   1
    2  100       2 0.014501468       0     1   1
    3  200       2 0.004117636       0     1   1
    4  300       2 0.011774388       0     1   1
    5  400       2 0.061472275       0     1   1
    6  500       2 0.083575322       0     1   1
```

I would like to plot the data in such a way that each of the four conditions has a separate colour. So far I've only managed to have different shapes for repcode=0 vs. repcode=1 and different colours for valcode=1 vs. 2 using the following line:

```
    dfPlot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pupil_size, shape=repcode, colour=valcode))
    dfPlot + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "line", size=1) +stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom="pointrange", size=1) + theme_bw(base_size = 10) + ggtitle("Pupil response") + ylab("Normalised pupil size") + xlab("Time relative to baseline (in ms)")
```

I tried inserting colour = c(repcode, valcode), but R gives me the following error message:

```
   Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:time, pupil_corr
```

The only other solution I could think of is to generate a composite variable of repcode and valcode and define that as colour. Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `interaction(repcode, valcode)` ?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much :)